# Creating a DateTime using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, viewmodel, automapper

I am struggling to create a DateTime object from (year, month, day) which is being returned from the database. I am rather new to AutoMapper so a nudge in the right direction would be great.

Here is the ViewModel containing the DateTime object and the three values that need to be used to create the DateTime:

```
public class EnquiriesListViewModel
{
    // other field elided
    public sbyte flightDay;
    public sbyte flightMonth;
    public bool flightYear
    public DateTime flightDate;
    // other field elided
}
```

I would like AutoMapper to construct the flightDate from the other three values. I have tried various approaches, some of which didn't even compile!

Like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<enquiryListEntry, EnquiriesListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.flightDate,  /* what goes in here? */);
```

Looking forward to your responses.

M

Comment: It would be helpful to see the definition of enquiryListEntry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<enquiryListEntry, EnquiriesListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.flightDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(src.flightYear, src.flightMonth, src.flightDay)));
```

Should do it.

Comment: @Richard, that's right, just realized it when I submitted the answer. Edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is coming too late but its good because it applies to .NET 4.6.1

```
Mapper.CreateMap<enquiryListEntry, EnquiriesListViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.flightDate, 
                 opt => opt.AddTransform(src => new DateTime(src.Year,
                                                             src.Month,
                                                             src.Day)));
```